# $(window).load and loading gif glitch

Tags: jquery

I plan to use a loading gif in my website. Unfortunately, the code doesn't work as it should. This is a snippet of code (which is very similar to several answers in stackoverflow) -

HTML :

```
<div id="load"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#load {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
  background: url(../img/load.gif) center no-repeat white;
}
```

JS :

```
$(window).load(function() {  
  $("#load").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

The problem I am encountering is that the loading gif NEVER fades out. This code works when I use `$(document).ready` instead. But it is pretty useless since the various images/textures do not load until much later.

Is there something wrong with the above code? Or does it have something to do with the fact that many images images/textures in my page pop up only after clicking a button/div? Does `$(window).load` load these images too (the ones which currently have `display: none`)?

Comment: _.delay_ doesnt work like that

maybe you could use `$("#load").fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");`
or
`setTimeout(function({
  $("#load").fadeOut("slow");
},2000)`


by the way, nice site.

Comment: @PaulJohnDiwa it is the same even without the delay....it has something to do with loading the window I guess. Thanks anyway, I will edit the question and remove delay.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ That load() method is removed, use: $(window).on('load', function ()...

Comment: @sinisake Thanks!! It worked